# Modularity and prime number sequence

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I tried to solve this modular equation involving first $n$ prime numbers. And it is:

$$2^{3+5+7+11+13+.....+p_{n-3}+p_{n-2}}\equiv p_{n-1}\ \left(\text{mod }p_{n}\right),$$

where $p_{n}$ is the $n$-th prime number.

I couldn't find any solution for this equation until first $300$ primes. Is there any solutions for $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solutions at $p_{n-1}=5813, 29537,$ and $ 44839$ [$p_n = 5821, 29567, $ and $ 44843$ respectively]. We're hitting a fairly random point in the power cycle so I see every reason to expect solutions to continue to appear occasionally.

Comment: Why P(n-1) and not P(n) ?

Comment: @norakbanges I will add those for ease of reference also.

Comment: This maybe very strange.but I'm never doing e-mail in my life..

Answer (score 1):

For what is worth, next solutions $\{n,p_n\}$ are:
$$
\{306\,311,4\,353\,467\}\\
\{859\,825,13\,174\,621\}\\
\{1\,700\,098,27\,291\,793\}\\
$$
There are no more with $n\le10^7$.

Comment: Yes, a $0$ missing. Thanks for noticing.