# sequence of primes satisfying a particular equation

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Do this equation have other solutions other than $P(52)=241$; $3^{5+7+11+13+\cdots+P(n-3)+P(n-2)}=P(n-1) \mod{P(n)}$. Here $P(n)$ is the $n$-th odd prime. I have checked $n$ up to $5500$, but I couldn't find any other solutions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modularity and prime number sequence](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1132216/modularity-and-prime-number-sequence)

Comment: @JuliánAguirre,no it's different 3,5,7,11 (odd primes only)

Comment: You are right. I retracted my vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

$$
{\huge3}^{\displaystyle\sum_{n=3}^{730690}P(n)}{\Large\equiv P(730691) \mod P(730692)}.
$$
$$\begin{align}
P(730691)&=11\,067\,689\\
P(730692)&=11\,067\,691
\end{align}$$
There are no more solutions with $n\le10^7$.